# How to call a method within an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a property within an object and I want the value to be whatever is returned from a method within the same function:

```
var model = {
  generateRandomNumber: function(){
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      return randomNumber;  
  }, 

  generatedNumber: this.generateRandomNumber()
};
```

But I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I just want to have the new property to contain whatever is returned from the method within the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the object (to call the function) until after the object exists.

You have to do this in two steps:

```
 var model = {
    generateRandomNumber: function(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        return randomNumber;  
    }
};

model.generatedNumber = model.generateRandomNumber()
```

---

Since the method doesn't depend on `this` (which begs the question of why it is an object method in the first place), you could define the function separately instead.

```
function generateRandomNumber (){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return randomNumber;  
}

var model = {
    generateRandomNumber: generateRandomNumber,
    generatedNumber: generateRandomNumber()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function generateRandomNumber is not accessible within the object declaration because the object literal hasn't been fully parsed. Try this:

```
var obj = {
    generateRandomNumber: function() {
        return this.generatedRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    }
}

obj.generateRandomNumber();
alert(obj.generatedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your referencing, using this.generateRandomNumber inside an object.. that won't work. Why not just do this:

```
var model = {
  generateRandomNumber: function() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*101;}, generatedNumber: Math.floor(Math.random()*101};
```

This would have the same effect.